# how to import my unix variable inside my perl command..?

Tags: bash, perl, unix

I am running below command on Bash prompt:

```
bash-3.2$ x=12
bash-3.2$ echo $x
12
bash-3.2$ perl -e '$age=$x; print "Age = $age\n"'
Age =
bash-3.2$
```

I am not getting the age/number printed..! How shall i import my unix bash variable inside my perl command..!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to `export x` in the shell. Then you can access the variable from Perl as `$ENV{x}`.

```
$ x=12
$ export x
$ perl -e '$age=$ENV{x}; print "Age = $age\n"'
Age = 12
```

Comment: Or, you can use temporary assignment `x=12 perl -e '$age = $ENV{x}; print "Age = $age\n"'`.

Comment: Good answer ++.  Have acknowledged on my alternative

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44039145/3544399) on this thread accesses the variable **directly through the environment**, which seems like a neater way.

Still, to demonstrate a way to use direct shell substitution (which has it's uses), then the right way to do it would be like this:

```
perl -e '$age='"$x"'; print "Age = $age\n"'
```

- `perl` sees this as it's input: `perl -e $age=12; print "Age = $age\n"`

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes for the -e parameter prevents the shell variable from being expanded. Use `$ENV{'myvar'}` to get the value of shell variable `$myvar`

And export the variable too as noted by the other answer.